Play m3u8 containing http urls in it
I need help. I have an m3u8 file with channels in this format:
#EXTM3U
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="5f4f1f6cb0c8e030be45f8a7e608ec73",AltynAsyr
http://192.168.0.85:9981/stream/channelid/1813991263?profile=pass
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="fa3cb7e489caf43110cf578b0d548647",Setanta 1 Sports
http://192.168.0.85:9981/stream/channelid/1689730298?profile=pass
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="6f680f8df9fcf830b7ddeab567b7f1c0",Setanta 2 Sports
http://192.168.0.85:9981/stream/channelid/219113583?profile=pass
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="b876d1c8a9551ebbbe5e06e80b48c25d",Match TV Fighter
http://192.168.0.85:9981/stream/channelid/1221686968?profile=pass
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="1dfb85f0b0d338761d62dcbfdb526372",Match! Premier
http://192.168.0.85:9981/stream/channelid/1887828765?profile=pass
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="a90787fa50d3d9bc42ceac478bdf23c2", Channel One
http://192.168.0.85:9981/stream/channelid/2055669673?profile=pass

I need to create a player that will play a stream from these channels, as well as with the ability to switch between them. I used Plyr in combination with Hls.js. It works, but only if m3u8 contains links to the same m3u8 or contains chunks with .ts files. I will be glad for the help provided. Thanks in advance!
